# access scenario object in cucumber in a particular step in cucumber java

Tags: java, java-8, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I want to access the current scenario object in a particular step and write specific dynamic data into report.

```
@Before
    public void before(Scenario scenario) {
        this.scenario = scenario;
    }
```

And in step:

```
this.scenario.write(dynamicValue);
```

but when I am using this method and trying to access the scenario, it is printing successfully on console but entire cucumber report gets erased and no steps are visible in cucumber report. Basically I want to add some details in the cucumber report and I am aware of the `@After` Scenario and it works perfectly fine but I want to add the dynamic details in Cucumber reports in a particular step and not at the end of scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I had solved similar problem by maintaining my steps's output/information in a map or list and embed the information in @After method. I think your scenario object's changes are ignored or not carried over.